# The component styled...has been created dynamically. You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

In ReactJS while using styled-component, I face the bellow issue when trying to generate styles dynamically.

Below is the error message 
The component styled.div with the id of "sc-fzqyvX" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
io
[Error spanshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/726r6.png)

Below is my code:

```
  const getColumn = (ratio) => {
    return (styled.div`
        flex: ${ratio}; 
    `)
  } 

const TableHeaderComponent = ({headers, columnRatio}) => {

return ( 
    <TableHeader>
        {
        headers.map((header, index) => {
            const Column = getColumn(columnRatio[index]);
            return(<Column key={index} >{header}</Column>)
        }) }

    </TableHeader>
 );
}

export default TableHeaderComponent;
```

I understand that I get this warning because I dynamically generate the styled-component through the getColumn method. But how can I get around this?

I can't get the dynamic 'ratio' value from props, because it keeps changing as I iterate.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can create a Column component as styles component and make use of props to set the specific attributes

```
const Column = styled.div`
        flex: ${props => props.ratio}; 
    `

const TableHeaderComponent = ({headers, columnRatio}) => {

return ( 
    <TableHeader>
        {
          headers.map((header, index) => {
            return(
               <Column key={index} ratio={columnRatio[index]}>{header}</Column>
            )
          })
        }

    </TableHeader>
 );
}

export default TableHeaderComponent;
```

Comment: That won't do, because the ratio value is not tied to the props. It keeps varying as I iterate through the header array.
In the below mentioned part of the code:
    <TableHeader>
        {
          headers.map((header, index) => {
            return(
               <Column key={index} ratio={columnRatio[index]}>{header}</Column>
            )
          })
        }

    </TableHeader>

Comment: That is why we are passing `ratio={columnRatio[index]}` on to column component

Comment: Thanks mate...That just worked!
I didn't know we can set props non-react functions like that.
Thanks again!

Comment: That is because of the special syntax of styled-component that make it look like non-react functions, but in a sense its just an HOC over the component

Answer (score 2):

This warning comes up to guide you improve your app's performance cause, every time that your component rerender all this components will be recreated to avoid this you must create the styled components outside of any React component.
Hope this answer help you

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.