# How to dynamically pass styles to styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I am trying to make a higher order component with text and an icon that uses a styled-component under the hood for rendering, and I would like to pass the computed styles to it dynamically without passing loads of props.

The code below is a simplified example and the `size` prop needs to be used in both the parent component and the css. Passing only the size prop isnt too big of a deal, but when you get to a large amount of props that need to be used in the parent component and for styling there is a lot of cluttered passing of props.

The first solution I came up with creates a new `styled.button` when needed and reuses the same `size` prop from the parent component:

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import { IconType } from 'react-icons'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button: FC<{
    icon?: IconType
    text?: string
    size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'
    onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler
}> = ({ icon: Icon, text, size, onClick }) => {
    const iconSize = size === 'sm' ? 22 : size === 'md' ? 26 : 30
    const iconElem = Icon && <Icon size={iconSize} />

    const StyledButton = styled.button`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 1rem;

        width: fit-content;
        padding: 0.55rem ${size === 'sm' ? 0.75 : size === 'md' ? 1 : 1.25}rem;
        font-size: ${size === 'sm' ? 1 : size === 'md' ? 1.125 : 1.25}rem;
        border-radius: ${size === 'sm' ? 0.5 : size === 'md' ? 0.55 : 0.65}rem;
        font-weight: ${props => props.theme.fontWeights.semiBold};
    `

    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={onClick}>
            {iconElem} {text}
        </StyledButton>
    )
}

export default Button
```

But styled-components doesn't let you dynamically create a component like that and throws a warming:

```
The component Button__StyledButton with the id of "Button__StyledButton-sc-3866117b-0" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
```

So next I tried something like this, which works, but is kind of annoying and feels redundant:

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import { IconType } from 'react-icons'
import styled, { css, FlattenInterpolation, ThemeProps, DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components'

const Button: FC<{
    icon?: IconType
    text?: string
    size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'
    onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler
}> = ({ icon: Icon, text, size, onClick }) => {
    const iconSize = size === 'sm' ? 22 : size === 'md' ? 26 : 30
    const iconElem = Icon && <Icon size={iconSize} />

    const styles = css`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 1rem;

        width: fit-content;
        padding: 0.55rem ${size === 'sm' ? 0.75 : size === 'md' ? 1 : 1.25}rem;
        font-size: ${size === 'sm' ? 1 : size === 'md' ? 1.125 : 1.25}rem;
        border-radius: ${size === 'sm' ? 0.5 : size === 'md' ? 0.55 : 0.65}rem;
        font-weight: ${props => props.theme.fontWeights.semiBold};
    `

    return (
        <StyledButton styles={styles} onClick={onClick}>
            {iconElem} {text}
        </StyledButton>
    )
}

const StyledButton = styled.button<{
    styles: FlattenInterpolation<ThemeProps<DefaultTheme>>
}>`
    ${props => props.styles}
`

export default Button
```

Is there a better way to do this that I am missing?

The library [`@compiled/react`](https://compiledcssinjs.com/docs/api-css) from Atlassian has a feature that allows you to put css styles right into an element like so:

```
const redText = css`
  color: red;
`;

<div css={redText} />;
```

Does `styled-components` have any such feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Get rid of warning when dynamically rendering React styled component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714638/get-rid-of-warning-when-dynamically-rendering-react-styled-component)? Declare the `StyledButton` component outside the other component's render, and use its props to pass the dynamic `size` value to it, e.g. `<StyledButton size={size} onClick={onClick} />`

Comment: @juliomalves As I stated, I'm aware that styled-components does not allow you to declare components inside render functions because it is inefficient. While duplicating all the props in an option, I was trying to avoid this as its quite verbose.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that bit. If the problem of this approach is the potential number of props you may need to pass, you could consider spreading the props you need on the styled component, e.g. `<StyledButton onClick={onClick} {...props} />`.